# Sorting hybrid lists in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, sorting, lambda

Say I have this list `l = ['the fountainhead','atlas shrugged', 1, 67, 12, 0]` which I want to sort so that the final result be `['atlas shrugged', 'the fountainhead', 0, 1, 12, 67]`. This means that strings and integers in the list should be both sorted in ascending order. If I use `sorted()` the digits appear first:

```
>>> sorted(l)
[0, 1, 12, 67, 'atlas shrugged', 'the fountainhead']
```

and if I use lambda, it cannot get past ordering the list as it contains incomparable elements of different type:

```
>>> sorted(l, key=lambda x:int(x))

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#13>", line 1, in <module>
    sorted(l, key=lambda x:int(x))
  File "<pyshell#13>", line 1, in <lambda>
    sorted(l, key=lambda x:int(x))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'the fountainhead'
```

As far as I know, there is no way to utilize exception handling when working with lambdas. This is just a simple example to illustrate the question. I'd like to know if there is a general flexible way to sort hybrid lists in Python. I have searched through relevant pages on SO but couldn't find a general approach for this.

Comment: Well, check the type of the object. If it is a numeric type then use the item as is otherwise use `float('-inf')`. A ternary expression can be used for this.

Comment: What's your rule for sorting? Should all strings appear before numbers? Or just strings starting with "a"?

Comment: @GregHewgill Strings need to appear first.

Comment: if there are multiple strings in the list should they appear in sorted order at the beginning of the sorted list ?

Comment: @ziddarth Yes, both groups need to be sorted. Strings only have to appear at the beginning.

Comment: What could a list of strings and integers even mean? Is the order you are arbitrarily desiring meaningful? Perhaps you should consider splitting this in homogeneous lists, or never have created the heterogeneous list in the first place.

Comment: @msw Both groups need to be sorted in ascending order. I am not sure what you mean by meaningfulness here.

Comment: "Both groups" okay, so they are segregated, you just have them jammed together into one list which is inconvenient and confusing. You are intentionally obfuscating the design for no stated reason.

Comment: @msw Indeed. This was just an inquiry to explore possibilities, totally off the cuffs ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that the first problem here is that you have a hybrid list -- In general, it becomes tricky to follow the code when you don't know what operations you can do on which element since they aren't all the same type.

There is no general solution (since there is no *general* way to know how to compare objects of different types), but you can definitely handle the case you have (if you must)...

```
import numbers
sorted(l, key=lambda x: (isinstance(x, numbers.Number), x))
```

should do the trick.  Basically, my key function returns a `tuple`.  Since `tuple` (and all python sequences) are sorted lexicographically, python will first look at the first element of the tuple -- In this case, it will be `False` (`0`) if the item isn't a number so those elements will appear first.

Demo:

```
>>> l = [1, 2, 3, 'foo', 'bar', 4, 8, -10, 'baz']
>>> import numbers
>>> sorted(l, key=lambda x: (isinstance(x, numbers.Number), x))
['bar', 'baz', 'foo', -10, 1, 2, 3, 4, 8]
```

Comment: This fails to sort the strings.

Comment: Yes. I am running Python 2.7 now, so that might be the reason:

`>>> sorted(l, key=lambda x: (isinstance(x, numbers.Number), x))
['The Fountainhead', 'atlas shrugged', 0, 1, 12, 67]`

Comment: What's wrong with that?  `'T'` sorts before `'a'` since uppercase letters sort before lower case letters...

Comment: Good answer, one could also use `sorted(l, key=lambda x: (not isinstance(x, str), x))` if for some reason u did not want to import Numbers